# LexikFormFilterBundle loses conditions from relations

Tags: php, symfony

I use LexikFormFilterBundle to filter orders but I'dont know why condition does not work works with the bundle: oa.status = active when I filter by "status"

Why the bundle loses conditions from getAllForActiveAccount function?

controller:

```
    $orders = $orderRepository->getAllForActiveAccount();

    $form = $this->createForm(OrderFilterType::class);

    if ($request->query->has($form->getName())) {
        $form->submit($request->query->get($form->getName()));
        $filterBuilderUpdater->addFilterConditions($form, $orders);
    }
```

Order filter type:

```
class OrderFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('account', Filters\EntityFilterType::class, [
            'label' => 'Account',
            'class' => Account::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('oa')
                    ->where('oa.status = \'active\'');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'row_attr' => [
                'class' => 'col-12 col-sm-4',
            ]
        ]);

        $builder->add('status', Filters\ChoiceFilterType::class, [
        'label' => 'Status',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choices' => \array_flip(Order::statusNames),
        'choice_label' => function ($choice, $key, $value) {
            return $key;
        },
        'row_attr' => [
            'class' => 'col-12 col-sm-4',
        ]
    ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
            'validation_groups' => ['filtering'],
            'method' => Request::METHOD_GET,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'row',
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'order_filter';
    }
}
```

OrderRepository:

```
public function getAllForActiveAccount(): QueryBuilder
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->join("o.account", "oa")
        ->where('oa.status = \'active\'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in source code...

config/packages/lexik_form_filter.yaml:

```
...    
where_method: and
...
```